# how to embed subtitle to a video file without burn (html5)

Tags: ios, html, macos, video, ffmpeg

i've a cdn hosting and there are some video files on it. and i've subtitles for videos. as you know, osx or ios doesn't allow subtitles on fullscreen mode. i've found a solution with ffmpeg (burning) but it burns video with hardcode:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo

is there any other way to do it without hardcode (maybe a media server)? because i've 5 different subtitles for each video file. and can't do it with hardcode.

any helps would be great..

best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I'm suggesting is like this.

```
ffmpeg -i input_video -i input_sub -c:s mov_text -c:v copy -c:a copy output_video
```

Here `mov_text` is the codec for subtitles and this will soft embed the subtitle without burning it in to the video. All other streams will be copied as it is. See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t8oUOHWufug) for a demo.

Hope this helps!